# Extensible type traits in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-traits

I want to write a generic serialization library which provides e.g. a generic `save` function.
The library contains custom type traits, e.g. `some_condition`:

```
template <typename T>
struct some_condition
{
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_same<std::string, T>::value ||std::is_arithmetic<T>::value ;
};
```

`save`'s behavior is selected based on `some_condition`:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<some_condition<T>::value> save(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << "these types will be handled in a specific way: " << value << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!some_condition<T>::value> save(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << "these types will be handled in another way: " << value << std::endl;
}
```

`save` shall be customizable for user datatypes, not only via overloading, but also generically via traits.
Therefore I created `trait_extension` which can be specialized for traits templates:

```
template <template<typename> class Trait, typename T>
struct trait_extension : Trait<T>
{
}
```

`save` has to be modified accordingly:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<trait_extension<some_condition,T>::value> save(const T& value) { ... }


template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!trait_extension<some_condition,T>::value> save(const T& value) { ... }
```

A user could now provide his own specialization of `trait_extension`:

```
template <typename T>
struct trait_extension<some_condition, T>
{  
    // user specific extension: exclude floats from condition
    constexpr static bool value = !std::is_floating_point<T>::value && some_condition<T>::value;
};
```

**My question::**

Is there a "better" / more elegant way to realize extensible traits?

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62f807031b148cb7)</kbd>

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to have a "general case" where is_string is defined as false, and have specialisations define whatever is considered a string?

Comment: Have you looked at the [C++ Container Pretty-Printer](https://github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint) for reference?

Comment: "However, this will only work if the `trait_extension` specialization exists before `print`." Huh?

Comment: @ildjarn `print` does not resemble the actual functionality, this was just an example; I am looking for advice how to implement extensible traits, I did not find any reference to that in cxx-prettyprint

Comment: @T.C. strange, when I tried that yesterday the position of `trait_extension` (above/below `print`) seemed to matter... tried it again, [now it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8399c021e4bc101); still, are there any "better" / more elegant ways on how to implement the extensibility feature?

Comment: Have you considered simply overloading the `print()` function? For example, `std::wstring` is a string, too, but writing it to `std::cout` fails and your type traits won't help. If the user could overload `print()` or at least the function (`operator<<` above) to write to an `ostream`, at least it could work in some cases.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, type traits are the wrong approach. The point is that "string" doesn't describe a type as "integral" or "pointer" or "POD" does! The difference is that while a string contains text, there is no common interface associated with strings, so you can't make programming decisions on whether something is a string or not, making your approach (or at least the example) flawed.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the user could overload print, but I want to provide to provide him with the ability to use his own type traits with SFINAE; however, there could be an overlap for some types which match both his type traits and the ones used in the library which would result in ambiguity if he just added his own `print` implementation with SFINAE.

Comment: Very interesting idea but why? What is the goal? If you want to have class extensions use can use class specialization. For example you can create your own specialization for `std::vector<int>` (of course it is a bad practice, but extensions are a bad practice very often) and rewrite whole class. And you do not need a special lib

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes, the example was poorly chosen, I updated the question

Comment: Is there a reason you think "extensible type traits" solves your generic serialization problem? Is there a reason you didn't post about that instead of this?

Comment: I would use the Eric Niebler's customization points technique from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4381.html

Comment: Or for further options see https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/a-customizable-framework/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your approach is elegant at all. It could easily spiral into spaghetti code and makes it difficult to maintain or use. I would instead adopt a "policy"-based approach, similar to the `std::allocator` class in the standard library. Changing behavior is a simple matter of implementing the allocator interface and providing it as a template parameter. Then everything works itself out automagically.

For one thing, in a "generic serialization" library, you need to worry not only about types, but also about localization. It could be something as simple as using `,` instead of `.` or as complex as uniform capitalization. With your approach, it's not very easy to modify the stream or locale (i.e, std vs boost) back-end, but with a policy based approach it's a matter of search and replace:

```
serialize<int, std_locale<int>>(32.000)
serialize<int, boost_locale<int>>(32.000)
```

This allows you to provide a set of "defaults" in say a master locale class ala `std::allocator`, and then the user can just inherit from that and change behavior for one or two types, rather than provide crazy SFINAE overloads.